# How do I calculate the day between start date and end date using COT

Tags: sql-server

Currently I'm using Code On Time to develop my system.

I got a default current date and time, after the user selects a completed date from lookup, I want to calculate how many days and hours have been taken by the user. 
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
declare @dateTimeNow datetime = getutcdate()
, @dateTimeThen datetime = '2012-11-28 12:00:00'

select case when DATEPART(hour,(@dateTimeNow - @dateTimeThen)) >0 then day(@dateTimeNow - @dateTimeThen)-1 else day(@dateTimeNow - @dateTimeThen) end days
, DATEPART(hour,(@dateTimeNow - @dateTimeThen)) hours
```

or

```
select DATEDIFF(day,@datetimethen, @datetimenow) - case when (DATEDIFF(Hour,@datetimethen, @datetimenow)) % 24 = 0 then 0 else 1 end  days
, DATEDIFF(hour,@datetimethen, @datetimenow) % 24 hours
```

Comment: my 'completed date' is unknown cause is selected by the user, or should I use DateDiif? the query should put in COT SQL expression?

Comment: Hey @Bella, I've provided an alternate method using DateDiff above should that be of any help.  I'm not familiar with COT and can't find much useful stuff online about it so can't easily advise.  If you're able to call stored procedures or user defined functions from it you could wrap the above code in a function/proc then pass in your variables as parameters?  Sorry I can't be more helpful on this one.